# Flag as duplicate: point to specific answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

There are cases when a question already has an answer elsewhere, but not all answers apply. Here is an extreme example:

*[Create grayscale bitmap image from byte[] in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936829/create-grayscale-bitmap-image-from-byte-in-android)* has a perfect [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963291/192373), but that answer is not the one accepted. It actually does not answer the question to which it was posted!

I added comments on both the question and the answer, and I marked the question with

> **This question already has an answer here**

But I am not comfortable with this resolution. I would rather have a way to point to the specific answer in the 'Duplicate' banner. Or maybe I should ask the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3496570/xar-e-ahmer) to copy their answer to the other question, instead of marking them duplicate?